# Why doesn't PNPM install the latest version of nested dependencies

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning, pnpm

I have a dependency [`antd@4.20.6`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd) in my project, it depends on `rc-trigger`. The version is defined as [follows](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/package.json#L156)

```
"rc-trigger": "^5.2.10",
```

The latest version of [`rc-trigger`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-trigger) is already "5.3.1".

Why is `rc-trigger@5.2.10` still installed after I upgrade from `antd@4.20.6` to `antd@4.20.7`?

**I know that the `overrides` field can be used to force the latest version to be installed.**

Comment: You probably need to regenerate your lockfile. delete it, `pnpm install` and then it should get the latest compatible version of rc-trigger.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` try this:

```json
{
  "pnpm": {
    "packageExtensions": {
      "antd": {
        "dependencies": {
          "rc-trigger": "^5.3.1"
        }
     },
  }
}
```